# the null space of a bounded linear functional is closed.

Tags: linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces, bounds-of-integration

What I have now is:
Let any sequence $\{$$u_n$} in the Null Space $N(L)$  approach to $u^* \in H$. So the limit of $||Lu_n-u^*|| \leq$ limit of $||u_n-u^*||=0$  for all $L$ as a bounded linear functional in $H$. Then $u^*$ is in $N(L)$ as well. So $L$ is bounded.

Can anyone help me double check if it is correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you just made some typos, but yes the main step is
$$0 \le \|Lu\| = \|Lu_n - Lu\| \le \|L\| \|u_n - u\| \to 0.$$
Note the importance of the assumption that $L$ is bounded.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! I'm wondering where does 0≤‖‖ come from ?

Comment: @Rubidium. Norms are always nonnegative

Comment: got it,thanks!!!